# Visual Studio Design view ignores CSS position: relative in design view

Tags: css, visual-studio

I am a big fan of adding CSS in a stylesheet for my applications to have the form contents centered in the browser so that no matter what the size of the browser window, the application or page contents will be centered horizontally.

The CSS Code I use to do this is as follows :

```
.panel
{
     width: 300px; /* Can be whatever value you need it to be */
     position: relative;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -150px; /* This is half of width */
}
```

However, when I do this for an application I'm working on in Visual Studio, it moves the contents half off the page in design view. It's like it's applying the left and margin-left CSS attributes, but ignoring the relative attribute. Do you know how to get Visual Studio to treat my CSS the same way a browser would so that I can apply my CSS positioning code and still work on the application.  As of right now, I have to comment out CSS above until I am completely done working on the project so I can see the content in design view.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I've never really used VS for design. Aside from other ways to center your content i.e. `margin: 0 auto;` it's best you preview your work in actual browsers instead of the design view of VS. VS traditionally has catered to developers. It's augmented by other tools such as Blend for core designers.